# Internal Error 500 with Post.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm a bit of a newbie (first post) and I'm stumped on this problem: I'm editing a theme function to calculate a percentage using a different function from the original.

The modified one seems to cause an internal error anytime I try to edit a page, post or media object in Wordpress. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Original :**

```
public function percent_completed( $formatted = true ) {
    $goal    = $this->goal(false);
    $current = $this->current_amount(false);

    if ( 0 == $goal )
        return $formatted ? 0 . '%' : 0;

    $percent = ( $current / $goal ) * 100;
    $percent = round( $percent );

    if ( $formatted )
        return $percent . '%';
}
```

**Modified :**

```
public function percent_completed( $formatted = true ) {
    $goal    = $this->goal(false);
    $getdata = $this->backers_count();

    if ( 0 == $goal )
        return $formatted ? 0 . '%' : 0;

    $percent = ( $getdata / $goal ) * 100;
    $percent = round( $percent );

    if ( $formatted )
        return $percent . '%';

    return $percent;
}
```

Can anyone see any reason why the modified function would cause problems?

In the error log I'm seeing:

> [05-Sep-2013 14:13:12] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' in /home4/....../class-campaign.php on line 337

which goes to the above function. Line 337, according to Notepad++, is:

```
$getdata = $this->backers_count();
```

**This is the `backers_count()` function** :

```
public function backers_count() {
    $prices = edd_get_variable_prices( $this->ID );
    $total = 0;

    if ( empty( $prices ) )
        return 0;

    foreach ( $prices as $price ) {
        $total = $total + ( isset ( $price[ 'bought' ] ) ? $price[ 'bought' ] : 0 );
    }

    return absint( $total );
}
```

Comment: The error logs should tell you what went wrong. Do you need instructions on "how do I debug PHP"?

Comment: As @rid asked, what does `backers_count()` do? That seems to be the source of your problem.

Comment: The campaign has a goal. For example, 30 units. When someone purchases 1 unit, the percentage_completed should increase the progress bar on the homepage. So backers_count is used to get the amount of "backers" or purchases of the Campaign. Then the percentage_completed calculates the progress based on the number of backers.

Comment: $getdata = $this->backers_count();
is line 337 according to Notepad++

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure the class-campaign.php file referenecd in the error message is the one you posted, and the file on the server matches the one you are viewing?